# How can I run Multiple Servers on Different Digital Ocean droplets with single domain name server?

Tags: domain-name-system, linux-networking, nameserver, digital-ocean

I am sorry for the newbie question. Let me help you to understand the complete scenario.

I already have 1 droplet at the digital ocean running OpenLiteSpeed server. Here, I am planning to add multiple servers in different droplets.

1. Droplet 1: US Datacenter: srv01.domain.com
2. Droplet 2: AMS Datacenter: srv02.domain.com
3. Droplet 3: UK Datacenter: srv03.domain.com

Let's assume all droplets will run Litespeed Server & CyberPanel.

Now, I would like to know if it is possible to have my nameserver something like following to point all the droplets.

- ns1.domain.com
- ns2.domain.com

If this is not possible is it possible to have something like this:

- ns1.srv01.domain.com
- ns2.srv01.domain.com

If both approaches are possible which do you recommend & why.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can register and point an unlimited number of different domain names to the same (pair of) name servers.

A single name server can host a nearly unlimited number of domains , each with their own unique records.

Comment: Do you mind to elaborate on how & where can I configure my DNS nameservers ns1.domain.com & ns2.domain.com to work for all the websites hosted in different droplets? Detailed instruction will be highly appreciated.